# Suggestion on how track down Google Cloud 429 issue

Tags: google-cloud-functions, gcloud

My http trigger cloud function just failed recently with a 429, which is too many instance. The cloud function has a min instance of 1 and a max instance of 4. During the error, the cloud function was idle until the call occurred. The cloud function did not start, so there is no call time in the log. Subsequent calls did not result in an error. The cloud function makes a web service call to external system on the internet.

My first thought was that the cloud function exceeded the maximum of 4 instance, but it turns out during that time period the cloud function was idle and using a minimum of 1 instance. The previous call was 2 hours ago meaning that no rate quota was exceeded. The cloud function show low memory usage and the instance count never rise above or drop below 1. The logs only states that the request was aborted because there was no available instance. This mean the function was never executed so there is no metric on the execution time. There is nothing else in the log.

What do you think it may be happening? Is it possible for the backend to killed the cloud function because it is idle. If that is case, wouldn't the instance count drop to zero and then restart back to 1 (due to min instance setting) and wouldn't that result in a log entry?

Comment: Do you have a billing problem?

Answer (score 0):

Based on this documentation on [troubleshooting Cloud Functions errors](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting#cloud_logging_errors_related_to_pending_queue_request_aborts):

> - `The request was aborted because there was no available instance`
>
>   - `severity=WARNING` ( Response code: 429 ) Cloud Functions cannot scale due to the [`max-instances`](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/configuring/max-instances) limit you set during configuration.

This is caused by either of the following:

- A huge sudden increase in traffic.
- A long [cold start time](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/execution-environment#cold-starts).
- A long request processing time.
- High function error rate.
- Reaching the [maximum instance limit](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/configuring/max-instances) and hence the system cannot scale any further.
- Transient factors attributed to the Cloud Functions service.

As you mentioned, the `max-instances` was set to `4`, and this may cause the error 429.

You could try the following solutions based on Google Cloud recommendation:

- For HTTP trigger-based functions, have the client implement exponential backoff and retries for requests that must not be dropped. If you are [triggering Cloud Functions from Workflows](https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/calling-run-functions), you can use the [`try`/`retry` syntax](https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/reference/syntax/retrying) to achieve this.
- For background / event-driven functions, Cloud Functions supports [at-least-once delivery](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/execution-environment#execution-guarantees). Even without explicitly enabling retry, the event is automatically re-delivered and the function execution will be retried. See [Retrying Event-Driven Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/retries) for more information.
- When the root cause of the issue is a period of heightened transient errors attributed solely to Cloud Functions or if you need assistance with your issue, please contact [support](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/getting-support).

Comment: Thanks, however what I have notice is: 
* There little traffic.
* The request failed right away since there was no execution time. The function didn't even run.
* The maximum instance is 4, and there was only 1.

The most likely cause may be a cold start issue or Transient factors attributed. I might just have to rewrite the caller to retry the cloud function in the event of this type of error.